# Lexical analysis on a series of tokens given regexes

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions, compilers, parsers

I am to parse through a series of strings with a given token list. I was wondering if my lexical analysis is correct.

```
T1 = { abc, abc1 }
T2 = { abd, abd1 }
ID = [a-z]+[a-z0-9]
NUM = 0 | [1-9][0-9]
```

`lexer.getToken()` will return the current token and advance the input buffer by one.
`lexer.peek(num)` will return the token at the index `num` and NOT advance the input buffer. `num` starts at 1 and 1 indicates the next possible token.

Here are the strings

`abc 202 02202 abcabd1 abd0abc1 a123 abd1 abd2 abd3`

and here are the function calls

```
t1 = lexer.getToken(); # will return t1 = {T1, "abc"}
t2 = lexer.getToken(); # will return t2 = {NUM, "202"}
t3 = lexer.peek(1); # will return t3 = {NUM, "2202"}
t4 = lexer.peek(2); # will return t4 = {ID, "abcabd1"}
t5 = lexer.getToken(); # will return t5 = {NUM, "0"}
t6 = lexer.peek(2); # will return t6 = {ID, "abd0abc1"}
t7 = lexer.peek(3); # will return t7 = {ID, "a123"}
t8 = lexer.peek(4); # will return t8 = {T2, "abd1"}
t9 = lexer.getToken(); # will return t9 = {NUM, "2202"}
t10 = lexer.peek(5); # will return t10 = {ID, "abd3"}
```

I got this because

`t1` will consume and return `"abc"` as conforms to `T1` and advance the input buffer

`t2` will consume and return `"202"` as conforms to `T2` and advance the input buffer

`t3` will return `"2202"` because we are currently at `"0"` since `"0"` conforms to regex `NUM` and we peek past it.

`t4` will find the next valid token which is `"abcabd1"`

`t5` will consume the `"0"` as conforms to `NUM` and advance the input buffer

`t6` will return `"abd0abc1"` as conforms to `ID` since input buff on `"2202"`

`t7` will return `"a123"` as conforms to `ID` since we are still on `"2202"`

`t8` will return `"abd1"` as conforms to `T2`

`t9` will return `"2202"` as conforms to `NUM` and consume `"2202"`, moving to `"abcabd1"`

`t10` will return `"abd3"` as conforms to `ID` since we are currently on `"abcabd1"`.

Does this logic look correct? I apologize if this is somewhat messy, just wanted to see if my logic is correct and I am following all regex/lexical rules.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Carefully check the use of `+` in the expressions for `ID` & `NUM`, and the semantics/specification of `lexer.peek(<argument>)`. Present the latter in your question if you want an answer to spell out somebody else's interpretation. Check [Which computer science/programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-site-fits)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's odd to say that "1 indicates the next possible token" when you intend to return the token *after* the first unconsumed token. Or do you allow $peek(0)$ to return the current token without consuming it? (Far and away the most common use for a peek function.) But that's just documentation, I guess.

`abd0abc1` is not a match for `[a-z]+[a-z0-9]`. `abd0` would match that regular expression; once a digit is matched, nothing more can be added.